# How to read one by one line from ONE file at unix and split into two files

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, sh

I have one input file, i need to read and apply some condition and route to two other files.

my input file, company.txt

```
100ABC COMPANY          
2pen9999out
2cow7777out
2goa7777out
100XYZ COMPANY 
2car9999out
2cow7777out
2HAT7777out
2BAL9999out
```

here, record start with 1 was header and 2 was detail

i need to create two file 100ABC.txt and 100XYZ.txt?

first i need to check

inline= =$( cut -f 0-1 $line)
  compnayName= =$( cut -f 4-6 $line)

```
if [ $inline -eq "1"` ] and $compnayName="ABC"
 if(record start with 2 and  position 4 to 8 has value like 7777)
    if yes,  route them in 100ABC.txt
```

output:100ABC.txt

```
2cow7777out
2goa7777out
```

in the same i need to check the next company XYZ,

if [ $inline -eq "1"` ] and $compnayName="XYZ"
    if(record start with 2 and  position 4 to 8 has value like 7777)
        if yes,  route them in 100XYZ.txt

like XYZ.txt

```
 2cow7777out
 2HAT7777out
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk '/^1/{close(f); f=$1 ".txt"} /^2...7777/{print>f}' company.txt
```

After this command is run, there will be two new files in the directory:

```
$ ls
100ABC.txt  100XYZ.txt  company.txt
```

The files will have content:

```
$ cat 100ABC.txt 
2cow7777out
2goa7777out
```

And:

```
$ cat 100XYZ.txt 
2cow7777out
2HAT7777out
```

#### How it works

1. `/^1/{close(f); f=$1 ".txt"}`

   If the current line starts with `1`, then close the file `f` (if it exists) and assign a new value for `f` consisting of the first field followed by `.txt`.
2. `/^2...7777/{print>f}`

   If the current line starts with `2...777` where `.` matches any any character, then print this current line to file `f`.

Comment: super sexy solution, I like it :-) Thanks

Comment: hello john, thanks for response. but I want exactly grab value eg.,7777 from position  4 to 8, i have given only sample file. any advise

Comment: @jcrshankar OK.  Please clarify.  What do you want to do with it __after__ you grab it?  How would the results be different from what I show?

Comment: hello john, i have added question with more details  at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018230/creating-two-files-from-one-file-using-unix please check once