# Creating two files from one file using unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, sh

I have one input file, I need to read and apply some condition and route to two other files.

```
100 COMPANY Records
500ABC COMPANY 345         
2pen9999out
2cow7777out
2goa7777out
500ABC COMPANY IN 456
2car9999out
2cow7777out
2HAT7777out
2BAL9999out
2BAL6666out
```

here, record start with 5 was header and 2 was detail

i need to create two file `ABC_COMPANY.txt` and `ABC_COMPANY_IN.txt`?

I have written below logic, which I want to convert using `awk` or other right approach?

```
NUMBER1="666"
NUMBER2="777"
while read line
 do

 REC_IND=`echo "${line}" | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}'`

 if [ "${REC_IND}" = "5" ]; then
 FILENAME="ABC_COMPANY"
 DEAIL_COMPANY=`echo "${line}" | awk '{print substr($0,3,7)}'`
  if [[ $DEAIL_COMPANY = "ABC COMPANY IN" ]]; then
    FILENAME="ABC_COMPANY_IN"
  fi
fi
#check for detail record
  if [ "${REC_IND}" = "2" ] ;then
 #substring to find value
 Value=`echo "${line}" | awk '{print substr($0,4,9)}'`
  #if record belongs to bank then route to the respective file
  if [ "$Value" = "$NUMBER1" ]  || [ "$Value" = "$NUMBER2" ] ; then
    echo $line >> ${FILENAME}".txt"
  fi
fi
done <  /bk/shan.txthere
```

expected output:

**ABC_COMPANY.txt**

```
2cow7777out
2goa7777out
```

**ABC_COMPANY_IN.txt**

```
2cow7777out
2HAT7777out
2BAL6666out
```

Comment: Why only with nos `666` and `777` ?

Comment: Since you tagged this `unix`, are you wanting solutions limted to POSIX shell? Or, do you have bash or another advanced shell like `ksh` or `zsh`? (it matters for string indexing, etc.) Why don't you include `...pen...` and `...car...` records in output?

Comment: In korn shell, you can easily use string indexes, e.g. `${variable:start:length}` (note: `start` starts from `0`) to extract any substring needed. That will allow you to easily parse the 1-st character and the `ABC.....` from each of the needed header records for use as a filename. See [Korn Shell Pattern Substitution Operations](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_05.htm) at the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a proper `Awk` script like something below. This takes care of achieving your requirement as stated in the question and creates two files `ABC_COMPANY.txt` and `ABC_COMPANY_IN.txt` with contents as mentioned in the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

$1 ~ /^5/ {
    gsub(/[0-9]+/,"")
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"_")
    header=$0".txt"    
    openhandles[len++] = header
}

$1 ~ /^2/ && $1 ~ /666|777/ {
    print > header
}

END {
    for (i=0; i<len; i++ )
        close(openhandles[i])
}
```

Run the script as

```
awk -f script.awk inputfile
```

You can use the command-line version of the script as

```
awk '$1 ~ /^5/ { gsub(/[0-9]+/,""); gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"");
gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"_"); header=$0".txt"; openhandles[len++] = header; }
$1 ~ /^2/ && $1 ~ /666|777/ { print > header }
END {for (i=0; i<len; i++ )  close(openhandles[i]) }' file
```